# Http Status Code for Custom Lambda Function NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In my lambda I am trying to throw custom error if some logic is incorrect.

I had tried: `callback(err)`, `throw new Error(err)`
It returned the error object, but am not able to update the HTTP response code: [image]
i.e.: I want to show `500` instead of `200 OK`.

Also in my AWS Integration Response, I have declared the response types.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your lambda code?

Comment: ` if(!event.client_id || !event.client_secret){
          const errorObj = { 
            statusCode: 500,
            body: "No client_id or client_secret in request"
          }
          // context.succeed(errorObj);
          // callback(errorObj);
          throw new Error(JSON.stringify(errorObj));}`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in Lambda. Adding the statusCode to the response object you return.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let response = {
      statusCode: '500',
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: 'error' }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
};
    return response;
};
```

[image]